# Laravel Отправка параметра в google form

Tags: laravel, google-forms

Есть проект на ларавел 5 нужно при нажатие на кнопку что бы пересылался парметр названия продукта в гугл форму .

http://404style.az/buynow/bag/2 (сслыка на сайт с кнопкой ордер =) )

Как вы думаете есть ли такая возможность ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Инспектируем форму и достаем значения атрибутов name у полей и атрибут action у формы:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Создаем собственную форму и вставляем полям такие же атрибуты name как и у формы в айфрейме:**

```
<form action="" id="gform-jquery">
    <label>Поле 1 обычный инпут
        <input type="text" name="entry.1708534700" class="req">
    </label>
    <label>Поле 2 текстарея
        <textarea name="entry.1715525179" class="req"></textarea>
    </label>
    <p>Поле 3 радиобаттон</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="entry.750520923" value="Вариант 1">Вариант 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="entry.750520923" value="Вариант 2">Вариант 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="entry.750520923" value="Вариант 3">Вариант 3</label>
    <p>Поле 4 чекбоксы</p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="entry.1217837295" value="Вариант 1">Вариант 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="entry.1217837295" value="Вариант 2">Вариант 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="entry.1217837295" value="Вариант 3">Вариант 3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="entry.1217837295" value="Вариант 4">Вариант 4</label>
    <label>Поле 5 селектлист
        <select name="entry.1912015558">
            <option value="Вариант 1">Вариант 1</option>
            <option value="Вариант 2">Вариант 2</option>
            <option value="Вариант 3">Вариант 3</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.635644082" value="Собственный HTML+jQuery">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

**Теперь отправим форму аяксом с помощью jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // после загрузки DOM
    $('#gform-jquery').submit(function(e){ // вешаем событие на отправку формы
        e.preventDefault(); // выключаем стандартное действие отправки
        var form = $(this); // запомним форму в переменной

        // добавим небольшую секцию проверки на заполненность
        var errors = false; // сначала ошибок нет
        form.find('.req').each(function(){ // пройдем по каждому полю с классом .req в форме
            $(this).removeClass('error'); // сначала уберем у него класс с ошибкой, на случай если он там есть
            if ($(this).val() == '') { // если оно пустое
                $(this).addClass('error'); // добавим к нему класс с ошибкой
                errors = true; // найдена ошибка
            }
        });
        if (errors) return false; // если есть ошибка то больше ничего не делаем

        var data = form.serialize(); // сериализуем данные формы в строку для отправки, обратите внимание что атрибуты name у полей полностью сопдают с нэймами у полей самой гугл формы

        $.ajax({ // инициализируем аякс
            url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1xwGBCGQyvim9DY0Teuwlq5AtE7DJUCSogSwgGC-dwFA/formResponse", // слать надо сюда, строку с буковками надо заменить на вашу, это атрибут action формы
            data: data, // данные  которые мы сериализовали
            type: "POST", // постом
            dataType: "xml", // ответ ждем в формате xml
            beforeSend: function(){ // перед отправкой
                form.find('button').attr('disabled'); // отключим кнопку
            },
            statusCode: { // после того как пришел ответ от сервера
                0: function (){ // это успешный случай
                    form.html('<h4>Спасибо!</h4><p>Форма отправлена блаблабла</p>'); // сунем в форму сообщение что все ок
                },
                200: function (){ // это тоже успешный случай
                    form.html('<h4>Спасибо!</h4><p>Форма отправлена блаблабла</p>'); // сунем в форму сообщение что все ок
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: спасибо за решение и вроде все хорошо но фактом не могу отправить форму дает вот такую ошибку  XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1xwGBCGQyvim9DY0Teuwlq5AtE7DJUCSogSwgGC-dwFA/formResponse. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.